# Discord.js timer with periodically updating countdown

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a timer command where a user could input something like [prefix]timer 10m and the bot will start a timer with 10 minutes, and every 20-30 seconds it updates itself, but I'm unsure how I could do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this may be using the `setInterval()` function.
You can use it to call a Callback-functions every time after a set interval has run out.

In your case, this Callback could be a function that updates a variable that is used to store the remaining time of the timer in seconds, e.g. like that:

```
var timer = 60;

setInterval(function () {
    timer--;
    console.log(timer);
}, 1000)
```

Note that the number given as a second argument is the time in miliseconds, so 1000ms would be one second.
If you dont want the function to output the current state of the timer every second, you can use a second `setInterval()` that only triggers all 30 seconds.

You can find more examples for the `setInterval()` function on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).